# How to add or load Mongolian language in Spacy NLP?

Tags: rasa

I am building Chatbot using Rasa framework and I need use to Mongolian language. But not listed here.

Answer (score 0):

Rasa supports spaCy which in turn supports a couple of languages. At the time of writing this answer it seems that Mongolian is not supported directly in spaCy, per guide [here](https://spacy.io/usage/models). That said, you can certainly make an assistant with Rasa without spaCy.

The main thing that I don't know is if Mongolian requires a specialised tokeniser. If it is "whitespace"-tokenizable then Rasa will be able to train a machine learning model for it.

It might be worthwhile to point out that there's an effort on the [rasa nlu examples project](https://rasahq.github.io/rasa-nlu-examples/) to support more Non-English tools. Disclaimer: I'm the maintainer of that project. But over at that project I maintain NLP tools that are compatible with Rasa, albeit somewhat experimental. In particular there's embeddings that support Mongolian. The [BytePairFeaturizer](https://rasahq.github.io/rasa-nlu-examples/docs/featurizer/bytepair/) uses `bpemb` which [supports Mongolian](https://nlp.h-its.org/bpemb/mn/). The same holds for [fasttext](https://fasttext.cc/docs/en/pretrained-vectors.html).

If you're interested in discussing your use-case in more detail, feel free to ask more elaborate questions over on the Rasa forum [here](https://forum.rasa.com).